# How to Reduce the Memory Usage in BULK INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, out-of-memory, bulkinsert

I am using Bulk Insert command to insert 4,910,496 records, as below:

```
BULK INSERT [MyTable] FROM 'F:\mydata.dat' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar', FORMATFILE = 'F:\myformat.XML', MAXERRORS = 2147483647, ROWS_PER_BATCH = 4910496, TABLOCK);
```

However, from time to time, the insertion will fail and I will get the following error:

```
Error: 802, Severity: 17, State: 20. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
```

I check online and see https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/16/sql-server-error-17300-the-error-is-printed-in-terse-mode-because-there-was-error-during-formatting/ , which said this error occurs because SQL Server is out of memory.

So, my question is, how to prevent SQL Server from out of memory in bulk insert operation?

Comment: Try reducing  the rows_per_batch = 10000

Comment: Plan B.. instead of running the Bulk Insert from SQL, try BCP from command prompt.

Comment: There could be many reasons for that particular error. Memory _might_ be one of them. Did you check SQL Server memory usage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-memory-usage?view=sql-server-ver15. The easiest way to prevent out of memory (if that's what it is) is to add more memory.

Comment: Try to temporarily extend the memory and see if it helps. Sp_configure ‘max server memory (MB)’,’1024′;reconfigure